# How to pass parameters from Eval to href

Tags: asp.net

```
<a runat="server" id="link" href='ProductDetails.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("productID") %>'></a>
```

Comment: Can you explain what error is occurring?

Comment: Upon clicking on the anchor link I get the following url in browser

http://localhost:1389/ProductDetails.aspx?ID=%3C%# Eval(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue.Thanks.

```
<a runat="server" id="link" href='<%# Eval("productid", "ProductDetails.aspx?ID={0}") %>'><%# Eval("productname") %></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space between the # and the Eval.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the entire string within the `<%# %>` block.

```
<a runat="server" id="link" 
    href=<%# "ProductDetails.aspx?ID=" + Eval("productID") %>
</a>
```

As an added note, I'd recommend using `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` so that if there's a character such as '%', your link won't break.

```
<a runat="server" id="link" 
    href=<%# "ProductDetails.aspx?ID=" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("productID"))%>
```